# how can i get my program to accept more than 9 digit numbers?

Tags: java, numbers, primes, numberformatexception

I am currently writing a small app that test prime numbers. It's gui based but I'm having one problem. I have added some constraints to the program where users can only enter numbers by using the numberformatexception handler but whenever a user enters a number that is more than 9 digits long, it no longer considers it a number. Is there a solution to this problem? I have left my code below.

```
static void validation() // This is what happens when the "Check" button is clicked
{


    // Retrieve information from the fields and print it out on the Frame
    if (jtfX.getText().trim().length() == 0) // Check if the field is empty
    {
        jlSolution.setText("You have not entered anything yet");

    }

    else // Otherwise...
    {

        try // In general....
        {

            if (Long.parseLong(jtfX.getText()) < 0) // Check if it is a negative value
            {
                                jlSolution.setText("The number you entered is less than zero");
            }
                            else // If it isn't...
            {
                                jlSolution.setText(new Algorithm(Integer.parseInt(jtfX.getText())).check()); // ....then check if this number is prime.
            }
        }

        catch (NumberFormatException nfe) // ... always catch those who refuse to follow simple rules!
        {
            jlSolution.setText("Numerical values only please. " + "You entered: " + jtfX.getText());

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: More code plz, `check()` ? `ALGORITHM()`One thing for more than 9 digit, you need to use `BigInteger`.

Comment: If `long` is enough for your purposes, that's a much smaller change than using `BigInteger`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the class `Algorithim` is a custom written class, you could replace the integer argument in its constructor with a `BigInteger` to hold larger values.

You would update your `jlSolution` field like so:

```
Algorithm algorithm = new Algorithm(new BigInteger(jtfX.getText()));
jlSolution.setText(algorithm.check());
```

Comment: Thanks allot, really appreciate it.